# Retorno de varios CASE em uma unica linha

Tags: mysqli, sql-select, mysql, order-by

Como converto esse retorno:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em uma unica linha:

```
548721  125 2   20836   20836   77821   77821   9999******9999  0   0   MASTERCARD  200 Cartao de Credito a Vista
```

Minha query:

```
SELECT
    CASE data_id WHEN 17  THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS bin_cartao,
    CASE data_id WHEN 18  THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS rede,
  CASE data_id WHEN 96  THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS bandeira,
  CASE data_id WHEN 203 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS nsu_sitef,
  CASE data_id WHEN 204 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS nsu_host,
  CASE data_id WHEN 205 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS nsu_credito,
    CASE data_id WHEN 160 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS autorizacao,
  CASE data_id WHEN 16  THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS aprovacao,
  CASE data_id WHEN 16  THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS aprovacao_adm,
  CASE data_id WHEN 104 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS cartao,
  CASE data_id WHEN 240 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS descricao,
  CASE data_id WHEN 294 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS cod_modalidade,
  CASE data_id WHEN 295 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS desc_modalidade
FROM
    sale_media_data
WHERE
    store_key = 2
AND pos_number = 52
AND ticket_number = 734701
AND DATE(start_time) = '2020-03-02';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  max(result.bin_cartao),
  max(result.rede),
  max(result.bandeira),
  max(result.nsu_sitef),
  max(result.nsu_host),
  max(result.nsu_credito),
  max(result.autorizacao),
  max(result.aprovacao),
  max(result.aprovacao_adm),
  max(result.cartao),
  max(result.descricao),
  max(result.cod_modalidade),
  max(result.desc_modalidade)
FROM
(SELECT
  CASE data_id WHEN 17  THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS bin_cartao,
  CASE data_id WHEN 18  THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS rede,
  CASE data_id WHEN 96  THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS bandeira,
  CASE data_id WHEN 203 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS nsu_sitef,
  CASE data_id WHEN 204 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS nsu_host,
  CASE data_id WHEN 205 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS nsu_credito,
    CASE data_id WHEN 160 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS autorizacao,
  CASE data_id WHEN 16  THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS aprovacao,
  CASE data_id WHEN 16  THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS aprovacao_adm,
  CASE data_id WHEN 104 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS cartao,
  CASE data_id WHEN 240 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS descricao,
  CASE data_id WHEN 294 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS cod_modalidade,
  CASE data_id WHEN 295 THEN data_value ELSE 0 END AS desc_modalidade
FROM
    sale_media_data
WHERE
    store_key = 2
AND pos_number = 52
AND ticket_number = 734701
AND DATE(start_time) = '2020-03-02'
) as result ;
```

Ou Algo Similar, como os valores diferentes de 0, são considerados maio, então será retornado somente os valores maiores de cada linha.